# Simply placing a toolbar inside of a Panel - Ext JS

Tags: extjs, panel, toolbar, xtype

I am creating a toolbar in my code below. What I'm wondering is how to place these inside a panel?

```
var toptoolbar = Ext.create('Ext.toolbar.Toolbar', {
    id: 'ttool',
    width: '100%',
    items: [
        {   text : 'MetaCenter',
            menu : {
            items: [
                { text : 'Wiki' }, 
                { text : 'JIRA' }, 
                { text : 'SVN' }, 
                { text : 'Sharepoint',
                    menu : {
                        items: [
                            {text : 'text 1'}, 
                            {text : 'text 2'}
                        ]
                    }
                }]
            }
        }           
    ]        

});
```

What I want to do is something like:

```
Ext.create.('Ext.panel.Panel', {
    id: 'panel',
    tbar: { //code to create the toptoolbar }
    ....
```

**EDIT:**

What I want to have is a very extensive drop down menu with sub menus on a toolbar, I'm trying to avoid putting all of that code to create that toolbar inside of my application. Instead I want to be able to call it from a variable (or better yet, a class?). Kind of like abstraction/encapsulation.

Is this a standard way of component instantiation or are there more-efficient methods?

Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the ExtJS docs for `dockedItems`, they give exactly this scenario as an example: http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.panel.Panel-cfg-dockedItems

Comment: Thanks Kevin, I know the dockedItems config works well, but I'm trying to abstract my toolbar configuration away from my app so all I have to do is call it's variable or class name to create the whole thing

Comment: With your code above, can't you just do `tbar: toptoolbar` in your panel creation?

Comment: That does work actually, thanks Kevin. Could I put the toolbar creation in a separate file? I'm guessing as a view?

Comment: 2 options: (1) Put it in a method like `buildToolbar` so it's not clogging up your `initComponent` (`tbar: this.buildToolbar()`), or (2) Extend `Ext.toolbar.Toolbar` in a separate file, and then do `tbar: Ext.create('My.toolbar')`

Comment: Exactly what I wanted (Ext.create). Thank you Sencha Mastah

Answer (score 1):

You can define the toolbar in the initComponent method of the panel.

```
Ext.define('MyApp.view.MyPanel', {
    extend: 'Ext.panel.Panel',
    height: 250,
    width: 400,
    title: 'My Panel',

    initComponent: function() {
        var me = this;

        Ext.applyIf(me, {
            dockedItems: [
                {
                    xtype: 'toolbar',
                    dock: 'top'
                }
            ]
    });

    me.callParent(arguments);
}

});
```

Comment: What I want to have is a very extensive drop down menu with sub menus, I'm trying to avoid putting all of that code to create that toolbar inside of my application. Instead I want to be able to call it from a variable (or better yet, a class?). Kind of like abstraction/encapsulation.